# How to show Qt.Tool window with minimize/maximize windows controls?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyqt5

I have...

```
class ToolWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """Generic window to be used as non-modal tool

    Usage:
        tool_win = ToolWindow()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('hello')
        layout.addWidget(button)
        tool_win.setup(layout)
        button.released.connect(lambda: print('hello'))
        tool_win.show()
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(ToolWindow, self).__init__()

    def setup(self, layout,
              window_title='Untitled', object_name=None, tool=True):
        """Setup tool window"""
        if tool:
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.setWindowTitle(window_title)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """Delete object when closed"""
        self.deleteLater()
```

However, I wish to add the typical maximize and minimize window controls to the window. I've attempted to add the following to the ToolWindow class without success (the tool window still doesn't show the maximize/minimize window controls):

```
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() |
                    QtCore.Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint |
                    QtCore.Qt.WindowMinMaxButtonsHint)
```

Is it possible to add these controls to a tool window?

Alternatively, can I create a non-modal window but which always sits atop my parent application and which shows the maximize/minimize window controls?

**Please note**, I don't want this tool window staying on top of ALL windows on my system. I only want it to always stay on top of my application.

Comment: You should state which platforms this needs to wotrk on.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use the `QMainWindow` class without any flags.  As long as the *tool window* is a child of the primary application window, it will stay on top of it (but not windows from other applications, like it would if you set the "Window Stays On Top" flag).

You'll need to change your `__init__` to accept parent arguments

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    super(ToolWindow, self).__init__(parent)
```

If you have multiple *Tool Windows* and you want them to stay on top in a specific order, you can call `my_tool_window.raise_()` to bring it to the top of the z-order.

Qt ships with a [window flags example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html). You may want to check that out to see how the different flags affect the window display and behavior.